# RxJava continue emitting after subscribing again

Tags: android, rx-java

i am struggling with implementation of RxJava with Socket.io. I have a problem to subscribe again to same observable, so i made an example and bit clearer code to understand.

here is the function:

```
private void testObservable() throws InterruptedException {
    io.reactivex.Observable observable = io.reactivex.Observable.create(new ObservableOnSubscribe() {
        @Override
        public void subscribe(ObservableEmitter e) throws Exception {
            for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
                java.lang.Thread.sleep(100);
                e.onNext(i);
                Timber.d("TESTOBSERVER emit %d", i);
            }
            e.onComplete();
        }
    });
    DisposableObserver observer = new DisposableObserver<Integer>() {
        @Override
        public void onNext(Integer value) {
            Timber.d("TESTOBSERVER observed: %d", value);
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete() {

        }
    };
    observable.subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribeWith(observer);
    Timber.d("TESTOBSERVER subscribe 1");

    java.lang.Thread.sleep(500);
    observer.dispose();

    Timber.d("TESTOBSERVER dispose 1");

    java.lang.Thread.sleep(500);
    observable.subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribeWith(observer);
    Timber.d("TESTOBSERVER subscribe 2");
    java.lang.Thread.sleep(500);
    observer.dispose();
    Timber.d("TESTOBSERVER dispose 2");
}
```

and here is what it prints

```
06-07 15:02:49.851 12649-12649/com.skunkaga.Skunkaga D/ThreadListPresenter: TESTOBSERVER subscribe 1
06-07 15:02:49.951 12649-12840/com.skunkaga.Skunkaga D/ThreadListPresenter: TESTOBSERVER emit 0
06-07 15:02:50.051 12649-12840/com.skunkaga.Skunkaga D/ThreadListPresenter: TESTOBSERVER emit 1
06-07 15:02:50.161 12649-12840/com.skunkaga.Skunkaga D/ThreadListPresenter: TESTOBSERVER emit 2
06-07 15:02:50.261 12649-12840/com.skunkaga.Skunkaga D/ThreadListPresenter: TESTOBSERVER emit 3
06-07 15:02:50.351 12649-12649/com.skunkaga.Skunkaga D/ThreadListPresenter: TESTOBSERVER dispose 1
06-07 15:02:50.861 12649-12649/com.skunkaga.Skunkaga D/ThreadListPresenter: TESTOBSERVER subscribe 2
06-07 15:02:51.361 12649-12649/com.skunkaga.Skunkaga D/ThreadListPresenter: TESTOBSERVER dispose 2
```

I have two questions:

1. Why it doesn't print out `TESTOBSERVER observed: 1`?
2. Why after second subscribe it doesn't continue with emitting 9,10,11,12,13?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. Why it doesn't print out TESTOBSERVER observed: 1?

Presumably because `testObservable()` is executing on the android main thread. So there is never a chance to observe values using `AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()` before it is cancelled.

> 2. Why after second subscribe it doesn't continue with emitting 9,10,11,12,13?

Because Observables are not stateful. Every `.subscribe()` call is independant of all others.
The reason it does not emit anything is because `Observer` cannot be reused. So since it was already subscribed and disposed it will not subscribe to the observable.

Comment: I undertand 2nd answer, but can you please elaborate more on 1st.

Comment: A scheduler like `AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()` schedules work for when that thread is done doing what it is currently doing. If you call `testObservable()` on that thread and use `Thread.sleep` to block then that thread never becomes available for those scheduled actions until after `Observer.dispose()` has been called. At that point it will never call `onNext`